# How to Compare a long value is equal to Long value

Tags: java

```java
long a = 1111;
Long b = 1113;
    
if (a == b) {
    System.out.println("Equals");
} else {
    System.out.println("not equals");
}
```

The above code prints `"equals"`, which is wrong.

How do I check whether a `long` value equals a `Long` value?

Comment: This code will not compile. The Second line requires a long value and you are providing an int. It should be Long b = 1113L; Even so, it does print the correct answer.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

First your code is not compiled. Line 
    Long b = 1113;

is wrong. You have to say

```
Long b = 1113L;
```

Second when I fixed this compilation problem the code printed "not equals".

Answer (score 10):

It works as expected:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    long a = 1111;
    Long b = 1113l;

    if (a == b) {
        System.out.println("Equals");
    } else {
        System.out.println("not equals");
    }
}
```

prints `not equals`.

Use `compareTo()` to compare Long, `==` wil not work in all case as far as the value is cached.

Comment: You are right, but it does not matter in this case. Autoboxing does its work.

Comment: @AlexR Auto*un*boxing. If it autoboxed `1234L` and `Long.valueOf(1234L)` *may* be non-equal. As ever with references, if `b` is `null` it blows up. (Oh and upper case-L suffix is preferred as it is difficult to mistake for 1.)

Comment: longs can not be compared with ==. The theory states that you need to use a simple trick like subtracting the one from the other and see the relevant difference.

Comment: What do you mean by you cannot compare longs with == ?        `for (int i = 1; i <= 1_000_000; i++) {
            final long l1 = (long) (Math.random() * 100_000_000);
            final long l2 = new Long(l1);
            System.out.println((l2 == l1) + "\t" + (l2 - l1));
        }` works...

Answer (score 7):

```
long a = 1111;
Long b = new Long(1113);

System.out.println(b.equals(a) ? "equal" : "different");
System.out.println((long) b == a ? "equal" : "different");
```

Answer (score 3):

`Long` is an object, while `long` is a primitive type. In order to compare them, you could get the primitive type out of the `Long` type:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    long a = 1111;
    Long b = 1113;
    if ((b != null) && (a == b.longValue())) {
        System.out.println("Equals");
    } else {
        System.out.println("not equals");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since Java 7 you can use [java.util.Objects.equals(Object a, Object b)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#equals(java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object)):

> These utilities include null-safe or null-tolerant methods

```
Long id1 = null;
Long id2 = 0l;
Objects.equals(id1, id2));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `equals` method to compare `Object` values.

**Mismatch example**:

```java
Long first = 12345L, second = 123L;
System.out.println(first.equals(second));
```

This returns `false`.

**Match example**:

```java
Long first = 12345L, second = 12345L;
System.out.println(first.equals(second));
```

This returns `true`.

Answer (score 0):

**First option:**

```java
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long a = 1111;
        Long b = 1113L;
        if (a == b.longValue()) {
            System.out.println("Equals");
        } else {
            System.out.println("not equals");
        }
    }
```

**Second option:**

```java
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long a = 1111;
        Long b = 1113L;
        if (a == b) {
            System.out.println("Equals");
        } else {
            System.out.println("not equals");
        }
    }
```